# Direct sum of Matrix algebras is not isomorphic to some semigroup algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra, semigroups

An $n \times n$ matrix unit is any matrix which has zeros every, except at one position where it has one. By $E_{ij}^{(n)}$ we denote the $n \times n$ matrix unit which has its one at the $i$-th row and $j$-th column.

Fix some field $F$, then surely the $n \times n$ matrices $M_{n\times n}(F)$ could be written in terms of the matrix units. And a more formal way to state that is that if $S$ denotes the semigroup of all matrix units with the zero matrix, then $M_{n\times n}(F) \cong F_0(S)$, where $F_0(S)$ denotes the [contracted semigroup algebra](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Semi-group_algebra),  which is the usual semigroup algebra (i.e. formal sums) with the zero element identified, i.e. $F_0(S)$ has a basis $B$ such that $B \cup 0$ is isomorphic with $S$.

This seems quite clear, but now suppose we look at
$$
 A = M_{n \times n}(F) \oplus M_{n\times n}(F)
$$
in the sense that the product of the direct factors is zero, i.e. think as an external direct sum. We can form the semigroup
$$
 S = \{ (E_{ij}^{(n)}, 0), (0, E_{ij}^{(n)}) \mid 0 \le i,j \le n \} \cup \{ (0,0) \}
$$
 with the product. Then I think we also have $A \cong F_0[S]$? But according to my text this should not be the case, so what am I missing. Why could $A$ be not isomorphic to a semigroup algebra?

**Background**: The text I am refering to is *The algebraic theory of semigroups*, Volume I by Clifford/Preston. In this book the following Theorem appears (page 167, Theorem 5.30):

> Let $A$ be a semisimple algebra of finite order over a field $F$. If $A = F[S]$ for some (finite) semigroup $S$, then one of the simple components of $A$ is of order $1$ over $F$.

Which clearly contradicts the above situation, where both compoents of $A$ have order $n$ as matrix algebras. Also note that $F_0[S^0] \cong F[S]$, where $S^0$ denotes that semigroup $S$ with a zero adjoined (i.e. taking a new element $0 \notin S$ and set $0\cdot x = x \cdot 0 = 0$ for every $x \in S$ and $S^0 = S \cup\{0\}$). Hence every semigroup algebra could be regarded as a contracted semigroup algebra.

Comment: Again, $A$ will be a *contracted* semigroup algebra, because the $\left(0,0\right)$ in $S$ maps to the zero matrix. I think the theorem you're quoting is about non-contracted semigroup algebras.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Why should that be a problem? Every semigroup algebra could be considered as a contracted one, see my last paragraph....

Comment: Nope. Not every monoid can be written as $S \cup \left\{0\right\}$ for a semigroup $S$. This works only if it has no zero-divisors.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes, sorry bad notation. I meant adjoining a zero. Which is always possible, just add an element $0$ and set $0\cdot x = x \cdot 0 = 0$ for every $x \in S$. It does not mean to take an existing zero!

Comment: @darijgrinberg I changed the notation to $S^0$ for $S$ with a zero adjoined.

Comment: So how do you want to apply the theorem? You have a contracted semigroup algebra. You would want to make it into an actual semigroup algebra. But you can only go the opposite way (in general).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Okay, I see. I somehow was confused. Maybe you can write it up as answer, so I can check it and give you credit for it!