# Subrings and quotients of finite semigroup algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semigroups, universal-algebra, finite-rings

Let $F = \Bbb F_p$ be a prime finite field and $R$ an arbitrary finite-dimensional associative (+ let's say unital) algebra over $F$. Then $R$ is a subalgebra (=subring here) of a matrix algebra $M_n(F)$ for some $n$, and $M_n(F)$ is a quotient of a certain semigroup algebra $FS$ with $S$ finite. (See e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453519) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910780).)

My questions:

1. does there necessarily exist a *finite* semigroup $S$ such that $R$ is a *subring* of $FS$?
2. and 3): same, but with "subring" replaced with "quotient" and "direct factor" (as in $FS \cong R \times T$).

Point 2) would have been obvious were we to allow infinite semigroups, as the free algebra is a semigroup algebra.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but for (1) can we consider $R$ as a (finite) multiplicative semigroup and then as a subring of $FR$?

Comment: There's a problem with $0$ of that semigroup — it becomes a basis element. But you can quotient it out and obtain the contracted semigroup algebra (see second link). My stupid question 1) was just about whether one could avoid that :-)

Comment: 1) would also be (too) trivial if $1$ isn't included into the ring signature: take a matrix algebra as a direct factor of a semisimple group algebra with a large irrep. I also know about Jan Okniński's book, but after a skimming through it looks to be mostly concerned with *cancellative* semigroups. (Maybe even these would suffice for 1)–3), I don't know!)